# What is the difference between ending lines with ellipses or without in literally written matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, line-breaks

### The basics

The regular way of writing matrices in MATLAB is the one-liner, like:

```
A = [3,2,1;2,1,3;1,3,2];
```

Breaking a command into several lines is done with 3 dots, like:

```
x = tan(...
    y);      % ie: x = tan(y);
```

### The problem

Now, combining these two rules to write a matrix *literally* (to clearly see its structure) results in:

```
B = [3, 2, 1;...
     2, 1, 3;...
     1, 3, 2];
```

MATLAB (in scripts and functions) however also accepts this form:

```
C = [3, 2, 1;
     2, 1, 3;
     1, 3, 2];
```

### The question

Are both ways of writing a matrix (`B` and `C` above) completely identical in terms of how MATLAB reads them? If there is a difference, should one be preferred over the other, and why?

**EDIT:** There are many ways writing a matrix in MATLAB, in one or on multiple lines, which all produce the same output. But is there one method that MATLAB understands best (i.e. minimum effort to understand the input properly)? Or is the effort on the program side always the same?

---

The reason why I ask: I just found myself using both methods in a single script, once to simply break a long line of numbers, once to to have a better view on the data.

Comment: Both ways are completely identical

Comment: Writing multiline matrix is an undocumented capability of matlab. You don't even need the `,` and `;`. I always choose the option `C` since it is shorter and more readable. I guess that `...\n` (where `\n` is a linebreak) is interpreted as a space character.

Comment: You might not see the difference in this example, but imagine you had fairly long row vectors: if you wanted to continue writing the row on another line, the only way to do it was using `...`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing:

```
A = [3, 2, 1; 2, 1, 3; 1, 3, 2];
```

Or:

```
B = [3, 2, 1;...
     2, 1, 3;...
     1, 3, 2];
```

Or:

```
C = [3, 2, 1;
     2, 1, 3;
     1, 3, 2];
```

Or **an even shorter way**:

```
D = [3, 2, 1
     2, 1, 3
     1, 3, 2];
```

Are all completely identical. `;` or line breaks are both used for separating matrix rows.

Simple test:

```
>> isequal(A,B)
ans =
  logical
   1

>> isequal(A,C)
ans =
  logical
   1

>> isequal(A,D)
ans =
  logical
   1
```

**So, which is best?**

Using `...` and line breaks (and `;`) is **completely unnecessary**, it is using line breaks and than overriding them with `...` for no reason. It is actually like writing:

```
B = [3, 2, 1; 2, 1, 3; 1, 3, 2];
```

Using `;` and line breaks is also unnecessary although it may be helpful adding `;` if you will want in the future to make them one line. It may also look more clear (opinion based?)

Using no line breaks is quite common, it is more compact although may not look as nice.

**To summarise**: Using `...` and line breaks (and `;`) is unnecessary and maybe confusing. Other option are mainly opinion based.

Comment: I agree that these methods all produce the same output (i.e. are identical to the user).  But are they also identical in terms of how MATLAB handles them internally? Is one method more _matlab-friendly_ than others (e.g. needs less effort on the MATLAB side to be understood correctly)?

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions. Please also see: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)